# React Native Modal Date Picker - why am I getting an extra window?

Tags: react-native

My React Native app (iOS) is using the [React Native Modal Datetime Picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-datetime-picker) package.  I have a button which, when clicked, should open the calendar so that I can pick a date.

However, when I click the button, I get the following modal window:

[image: Extra modal window]

If I then click on the date in that window, I see the calendar:

[image: Calendar window]

I want the calendar to appear when I click the button initially.

Here's the relevant code:

```
  const [isDatePickerVisible, setIsDatePickerVisibility] = useState(false);

  const showDatePicker = () => {
    setIsDatePickerVisibility(true);
  };

  const hideDatePicker = () => {
    setIsDatePickerVisibility(false);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.inputTitle}>DATE OF BIRTH</Text>
      <View style={styles.dateInput}>
        <TextInput
           editable={false}
           style={styles.input}
           value={dateOfBirth}
        />
        <Button transparent onPress={showDatePicker}>
          <Icon
            type="FontAwesome5"
            name={'calendar-alt'}
          />
        </Button>
        <DateTimePickerModal
          isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
          mode="date"
          onConfirm={handleDateSelection}
          onCancel={hideDatePicker}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
```

Has anyone else seen this behaviour? Or can anyone suggest what I can do about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> UIDatePicker now has a property called datePickerStyle. You can choose
> between .compact and .inline - both new to iOS 14 - or .wheel, which
> is the old style we have known for over a decade.

[link](https://www.andyibanez.com/posts/new-uidatepicker-ios14/)

you are viewing the default `.compact` style

[react-native-modal-datetime-picker](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker) library have fixed this issue

check your library version and update library version >9.0.0

> Fix support of iOS 14 by defaulting the community datetimepicker
> display to "display" (you can still manually override it if needed).

https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker/releases/tag/v9.0.0

**Note** : You need at least @react-native-community/datetimepicker@3.0.0 for
this version to work correctly.

shortcut solution without update . Add in AppDelegate.m (but it has [alignment issue](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker/issues/488))

```
if (@available(iOS 14, *)) {
    UIDatePicker *picker = [UIDatePicker appearance];
    picker.preferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyleWheels
 }
```